# How to call ASCX page Function on ASPX page?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls, webusercontrol

I add the WebUserControl in runtime, so I can't use `MyWebUserControl.MyFunction()`, I have a MasterPage and I tried this:

```
_MainContentPage = CType(_Page.Form.FindControl("MyContentPlaceHolder"), ContentPlaceHolder)
CType(_MainContentPage.FindControl("MyWebUserControl"), myType)
```

But `_MainContentPage.FindControl("MyWebUserControl")` returns a TableCell.

The way I add the WubUserControl:

```
tcValue = New TableCell()      
tcValue.Controls.Add(_Page.LoadControl("Paht/WebUserControl"))
tcValue.ID = "MyWebUserControl"
```

Well thats cause `_MainContentPage.FindControl("MyWebUserControl")` returns a TableCell
but how to get the Webcontrol and call the Function.

Comment: You probably have to use reflection to probe the User control class and then invoke the method.

Comment: thank you, but i already made it(see the question update)

Comment: Assuming your ascx is in a placeholder, could you loop through the controls in the placeholder and do something like `If (TypeOf(control) Is MyAscx) Then DirectCast(control, MyAscx).MyMethod()`?

Comment: nice idea valverij, thank you, but is that a not very efficient way?

Comment: It really depends on how your ascx is added to your placeholder and how many controls your placeholder has in it. If it only contains a few, the difference is probably negligible. It it has a few hundred, then you'll probably see a slight performance hit. Really, use whatever you feel is most readable and maintainable down the road.  I'd recommend staying clear of hardcoding ID's if possible, though, as well as keeping aspx- and control-specific code off of the master page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is get the TableCell and then find the control, after that call the function.

```
_MainContentPage = CType(_Page.Form.FindControl("MyContentPlaceHolder"),ContentPlaceHolder)
MyTableCell =  CType(_MainContentPage.FindControl("MyWebUserControl"), TableCell)
MyWebControl = CType(MyTableCell.Controls(0), MyType)
MyWebControl.MyFunction()
```

Answer (score 0):

How difficult is to make that function as a web method or extract that function in a asp.net http handler to be accessed globally. I think this way you can make it better rather than using reflections and other things to access it.